# MS Word (Office 2016) Insert Hyperlink -- Certain Letter Keys Not Working

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks, hyperlink, microsoft-word-2016

I'm inserting hyperlinks to authors' names to link them to their respective entries in my References list. All entries have been bookmarked.

When I open Insert Hyperlink I see the list of bookmarks, which is pretty long.

To navigate my way through the list with ease, I can press letter keys (e.g. D) to take me to the first entry starting with that letter (e.g. **Delaware**)

[image: Insert Hyperlink Window]

However, this doesn't work for all letters. It does works for most letters, but not for J, K, M, and P-Z. This means that if I press them, the cursor selector doesn't move down or up the list.

Is there a known fix to this?

Comment: You may want to insert Cross-References instead.  To work on this would require that someone create a document of their own with such bookmarks to test. It would help if you could create a short document with such bookmarks and save it on DropBox and post a view link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quick check with my MSWord (Office 365) and I can navigate to Letter M or Z.
I noticed the keyboard navigation on [Insert Hyperlink for Place in this Document (Bookmark)] is case sensitive and exact (non-fuzzy) match (eg. to navigate "Microsoft", "M" work fine but "m" does not work, and "L" does not move the position near "Microsoft" if there are no entries starting with "L").

Comment: You're 100% correct. The problem with the letters I mentioned earlier is that there are Headings (or sub-headings) in my document that begin with those letters (in capitals) and are placed higher than the bookmarks in the list. So the problem is caused by Word not allowing you to press "v" to get to a bookmark starting with "v" if there is a heading (or any previous item) starting with "V". Bizarre to say the least.

Comment: Unless you need hyperlink formatting in the document, try the Cross-Reference method. It separates the headings from the bookmarks.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I will next time for sure. The problem rn is that I'm adding links retroactively on someone else's doc, and if I try to use the Cross-Reference method I have to manually edit the display text of each reference which differs from the linked element (i.e. the entry in the references list). Plus references in the running text to the same element don't always look the same: e.g., Peters (2002) and (Peters 2002: 34). So I need to readapt them manually. With the Hyperlink method I can just select the text I want to link and then insert the link.